# how to implement Pendo in nextjs 13?

Tags: analytics, next.js13, pendo

I am working on nextjs 13.4 and want to install pendo on my application. I couldn't find anything about it on their docs.

can someone give the directions how to install pendo in nextjs 13 project?

tried putting the provided snippet inside script tags on Layout.tsx but I think it's stupid to do that